Astable multivibrator, potentialy bad circuit
I found this circuit scheme in my examples, and i think that this circuit wont work.

Aside protection diodes of CMOS inverters, there is this diode pointing in the first inverter(left one), how I understand it, voltage on the left side of capacitor needs to be above Vdd + 2Vd to make diodes conduct, if its below the input of inverter will be in high impedance state. So, input of the first inverter will never go to zero. So this circuit cant oscillate.
Can someone help me if I am misunderstanding something

Yes, I remember this circuit without the diode. But if you use a leaky OA150 germanium diode there it might work.

Without context of the original document, this circuit seems a strange beast.  I believe it will oscillate, but half the duty cycle depends on the R3 * C1 time constant, and the other half duty cycle will be very long, relying on parasitic effects of the reverse leakage current of the left diode and the magnitude of the tiny parasitic input capacitance of the left gate and its protection diodes.  As hinted by @Jens comment, the reverse leakage of the left diode would have to be larger than the reverse leakage of the protection diode to Vdd for the input to ever go low and to answer the OP question of "will this circuit actually oscillate?"  Seems like the circuit is more of a pulse generator than an oscillator, if it works at all.
For quick qualitative analysis let's pretend the right gate and C1 are not present (as C1 is open in steady state analysis anyway).  If we assume infinite input impedance on the left gate inputs with no parasitic capacitance, then the left diode just shifts the input thresholds down a diode drop and is also irrelevant.  This simplifies the core circuit to a single inverter with feedback, which would have very high frequency. Now lets try to figure out how the addition of C1, R3, the right gate, and the left diode change the oscillator behavior.
Adding in C1 and R3 to the feedback is going to slow down the feedback cycle and lower the maximum frequency of oscillation. If right side of C1 was just connected to ground, the R*C time constant provides simple symmetric extension of high/low time, basically lowering the frequency of oscillation.
When the right gate is added, now C1 acts as a charge pump because its right side is being switched between Vdd and ground during oscillation cycles which creates much larger transient voltages at the bottom net (R3 side of C1), and now C1 has differential transient voltage swings approaching 2*Vdd. Unclear why this wider transient swing is useful, and side effect is that now necessary to also add protection diodes at the gate inputs to avoid damaging over voltage and under voltage conditions. Now also R1+R2 has small effect on part of duty cycle where feedback is above Vdd, again unclear why this is desirable.
Finally, with the addition of the left diode, now the circuit has trouble transitioning from the state with the left gate input high (regardless of presence of right gate or not) because the current path to discharge the left gate's input capacitance via low feedback voltage is blocked. After a long time, however, if the very small reverse leakage current back through left diode (maybe plus reverse leakage on low side protection diode to ground) is greater than the reverse leakage through the higher side protection diode to Vdd, the tiny input capacitance will eventually discharge through R1+R2+R3 to fall below low input threshold, and the oscillator state changes again. The time in this state (with A low) is not possible to predict without measurements of these parasitic properties. This effect seems independent of the addition of the right gate, and same effect could be achieved with right side of C1 connected to ground instead.
The state with left gate input low (and with A high) has a duration simply dominated by C1 and R3 time constant. Per OP question, the left diode will conduct as long as the R1 side is more than a diode drop above the input of the left gate, which occurs is while the feedback voltage is high and then the cycle repeats.  Again, not clear why extending half the duty cycle to very long and hard to predict duration is helpful.
